# Delete last Array Data on C

Tags: c

I want to make a simple coding, just delete the last array data when i input Y.

I have code like this:

```
void deletedata(){
//system("cls");
char input;
char nama[50][50];
char nim[50][50];
float ip[50];
printnama();

do{
printf("Wanna delete the last data for sure [Y\N] : ");
scanf("%c",&input);fflush(stdin);
}while(input!='Y' || input!='N');
    if(input=='Y'){
        nama[count]={" "};
        nim[count]={" "};
        ip[count]={" "};
        printf("Delete Success");
    }else if(input=='N'){
        printf("Ok");
    }
}
```

in my VS2010 Express, it says nama[count] must be a modifable value.
What should i do?

First I input name,nim and number.
Then on menu3 i want to delete the last nama,nim,and ip that i just inputted.

This is the global variable that I made

```
int count=0;
char nama[50][50];
char nim[50][50];
float ip[50];
```

Comment: `while(input!='Y' || input!='N');` should be `input != 'Y' && input != 'N'` otherwise as soon as you enter valid input (e.g. `N`) the loop with stop because `'N' != 'Y'` will return `true` and since it's `OR` the loop will run again.

Comment: Already try the  '\0' but still cannot.

Comment: Shouldn't this `while(input!='Y' || input!='N');` be `while(input!='Y' && input!='N');`?

Comment: `strlen(s) - positive_value` in general is a straight route into disaster (sooner or later). Avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing right here:

```
    nama[count]={" "};
    nim[count]={" "};
    ip[count]={" "};
```

Is not valid C code because you can't explicitly assign an array to a char. In C you can't delete from an array in the sense it won't exist in memory but you can assign a nul terminator to prevent any code from reading further once it reaches the last element.

Also you never initialize `count` which you can replace with the function `strlen` and substract one to get the last index in your array.
So try:

```
    nama[strlen(name)-1][strlen(name[0])-1][0]='\0';
    nim[strlen(nim)-1][strlen(nim[0])-1][0]='\0';
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(ip)/sizeof(ip[0]), ip[i] != 0.0f; i++); // count the elements until you reach a value of 0.0f (this won't work if you have any values with 0.0f in your array)
    if(i>=sizeof(ip)/sizeof(ip[0]) i--;
    ip[i]=0.0f;
```

Assuming the outer most dimension for `nama` and `nim` are the same and the inner most dimension (the single one) for `ip` is same length you can simply set count to `strlen(name[strlen(name)-1])-1` and then do:

```
    count = strlen(name[strlen(name)-1])-1;
    nama[strlen(name)-1][count]='\0';
    nim[strlen(nim)-1][count]='\0';
    if(ip[0]!=0.0f) ip[count]=0.0f;
```

You can also simplify by adding another variable `inner_count`, because you dont want to call `strlen(name)-1` more than once. So assuming again `name` and `nim` will always be the same length in both inner and outer dimensions and that `ip` will have the same length as the outer dimension you can do this.

```
    inner_count = strlen(name)-1;
    count = strlen(name[inner_count])-1;
    nama[inner_count][count]='\0';
    nim[inner_count][count]='\0';
    if(inner_count==50) ip[count]=0.0f; // this assumes all arrays have length of 50.
```

Also what you must understand is that you can't really assign a nul terminator to your `ip` array and nor can you use `sizeof` to determine the length. You can assume it's the same length as the others array in your case or get the length by counting until you reach a value equal to 0.0f;